# Save json data (multiple items) into a map

Tags: dart, flutter

i Have a json file that is fetched from my server, i'd like to save the data into a map using a model, what's the proper way to do it?

I've created a model to decode the json data. My json file has some "[ ]" if i use another json file (single item) without "[ ]" it works but not with the bracket.

Here is my model

```
class RestoModel {
  // int id;
  String name;
  RestoModel(this.name);

  RestoModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    name = data['name'];
  }
}
```

My fetch function

```
  List<RestoModel> restaurantList = [];

  void fetchRestaurants() async {
    var response = await get('https://link/get_list.php');
    var data = RestoModel.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
    setState(() {
      restaurantList.add(data);
      print(response.body);
    });
  }
```

i get this error

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Here is my json data

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Resto 1"},{"id":"3","name":"Resto 2\r\n"}]
```

but my code works with this json data

```
{
  "name": "beatae et provident et ut vel",
}
```

I want the json file to be saved in the List but i get this error

```
Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"id":"1","name":"Resto 1"}` is a map, `[{"id":"1","name":"Resto 1"},{"id":"3","name":"Resto 2\r\n"}]` is a List of Map. So basically when you're decoding your json, you've ended up with list of model, id:1 and id:2. You're trying to give List of dynamics to your named constructor which takes a single Map as a parameter, not list of them.

Try this:

```
  Iterable i = json.decode(response.body);
  List<RestoModel> restaurantList = i.map((model) => RestoModel.fromJson(model)).toList();
```

In this code, I have an iterable, and for each restaurant data in that iterable I'm creating restomodel from json.

Comment: Thanks, it's working no more error, but when i print restaurantList i get this message ``` [Instance of 'RestoModel', Instance of 'RestoModel']``` not the actual data

Comment: Yes, because it's the instance of the RestoModel. What were you expecting? You can reach datas with restaurantList[0].name, where 0 is the index of the List. When you print instance of a class, it prints Instance of 'ClassName', it never spreads all the properties of an object, unless you've told it to do so :)

Comment: Never mind it's working fine :) thanks you mirkancal